# Add prefix to tableview javafx

Tags: java, user-interface, javafx, tableview

I would like to add prefix to my table-view, i read the docs there's no such functions.. How could this be done? Below is my java codes, please don't hate me.IN the code below I've created a tableview which connects to a pojo class called "citizen", note that the table is working great i just need to add some prefix in , for example in the waste column there should be prefix "kg"

```
       private AnchorPane root;
    @FXML
    public TableView<citizen> scheduledCitizenTable;
    @FXML
    private Button approveBtn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<citizen, Integer> idColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<citizen, String> nameColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<citizen, String> addressColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<citizen, String> arrivalColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<citizen, String> departureColumn;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<citizen, String> vehicleId;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<citizen, Integer> waste;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<citizen, String> remarks;
VehicleRoutingProblem vpr = new VehicleRoutingProblem();


  public static ObservableList<citizen> List = FXCollections.observableArrayList(

           // new citizen(1,"testing","testing","testing","testing")

);


    public ObservableList<citizen> getList() {
        return List;
    }

    public void setList(ObservableList<citizen> List) {
        this.List = List;
    }
    @Override
    public void initialize(URL url, ResourceBundle rb) {
        //System.out.println("List contains"+List.size());
try{
        vehicleId.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<citizen,String>("vehicleid"));
        idColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<citizen, Integer>("citizenId"));
        nameColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<citizen, String>("citizenName"));
        addressColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<citizen, String>("citizenAdress"));
        arrivalColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<citizen, String>("arrivalTime"));
        departureColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<citizen, String>("Departure"));
        waste.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<citizen,Integer>("waste"));
        remarks.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<citizen, String>("remarks"));
        //actionColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("citizenId"));;
        vehicleId.setCellFactory(column -> {
    return new TableCell<citizen, String>() {
        @Override
        protected void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
            super.updateItem(item, empty);

            if (item == null || empty) {
                setText(getText());
                setStyle("");
            } else {
                if (item.equals("vehicle1")) {
                    setText(getText());
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: yellow");
                    System.out.println("getting the text for vehicle 1"+getText());

                } else {
                    setText(getText());
                    setStyle("-fx-background-color: tomato");
                }
            }
        }
    };
});
        scheduledCitizenTable.setItems(List);}catch(NullPointerException e){};



    }





}
```

Comment: Remove `setText(getText());` and `try { ... } catch (NullPointerException e) {}` The former does not change anything, the latter just hides the exception that would provide information about why your application is in a state it's not supposed to be in... But why don't you apply your knowlege about modifying cells based on the content  (as demonstrated with the `vehicleId` column) to the `waste` column and set the `text` property to `""` or `item + " kg"`???

Answer (score 0):

as fabian said in his comment !
you can do exactly the same as you did for vehicleId and add "kg" to every row of the column waste !

```
waste.setCellFactory(new Callback<TableColumn<citizen,Integer>,TableCell<citizen,Integer>>() {
            public TableCell<citizen,Integer> call(TableColumn<citizen,Integer> param) {
                return new TableCell<citizen, Integer>() {

                    @Override
                    public void updateItem(Integer item, boolean empty) {
                        super.updateItem(item, empty);
                        if(!empty)
                        setText(item.toString()+" kg");
                        else
                        setText("");
                    }
                };
            }
        });
```